# How to model a user, coach relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, activerecord, model

In my model I have a user. The user is the athlete. A user may also be a coach to any other user. How to model this?

I have:

`@user.coach?` => true/false

`@user.is_a_coach_of?(other_user)` => true/false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a user can only have one coach, then you can have a coach association on the users table back to the users table.  The classic example of this is an employees table, where every employee has exactly one manager (except the CEO).

```
class User
  has_one :coach, :class_name => "User"
  has_many :coachees, :foreign_key => :coach_id, :class_name => "User"

  def coach?
    0 < coachees.count
  end

  def is_a_coach_of?(other_user)
    coachees.include?(other_user)
  end
end
```

If a user could have many coaches, then use a coaches table, with fields, user_id (for the coach) and coachee_id for the user that she coaches.

```
class Coach
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :coachee, :class_name => "User"
end

class User
  has_many coaches, :foreign_key => :coachee_id
  has_many coach_users, :through => :coachs, :source => :user
  has_many coachees, class_name => "Coach"
  has_many coachee_users, :through => :coachees, :source => :coachee

  def coach?
    0 < coachees.count
  end

  def is_a_coach_of?(other_user)
    coachee_users.include?(other_user)
  end
end
```

Comment: A user could potentially have many coaches =\ How would you do it in that case?

Answer (score 0):

I would have table representing relationships between athletes and their coaches - a row for each Athlete/Coach relationship - where both Coach and Athlete IDs are related to the User data.

```
CoachID | AthleteID
```

If any User can be a coach, then that's all you need, but if you want to restrict "coaching" to certain users, add an "IsCoach" property to the User table

Comment: Could you show me that in activerecord syntax by any chance? Just to be clear? :) Thanks!